# icecandidate event not getting fired in webrtc

Tags: angular, webrtc

I am trying to setup `webrtc` in angular. I am following up this guide which is in pure javascript:

[WebRtc Guide (Go to 5th step)](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/webrtc-web/#2).

It works perfectly. But in angular, I tried the same thing, with minor modifications, but `icecandidate` event is not getting fired.

Here is the link to my code:

[StackBlitz Link to my code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mtwipg)

I am not sure why `icecandidate` event is not getting fired. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to get the solution? I am also stuck at the same thing except I am implementing the same code in Vue.js.